# If B is a subset of inner product space V, show orthogonal complement of B is a subspace of V

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let *V* be a inner product space and *B* be a **subset** (not subspace) of *V*.

Is then *B┴* a **subspace** of *V* ?

There is a guy [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dytAXeDPJW8) that allegedly proves so, but I can't quite follow. Any heads-up or a counter-example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed true and not very difficult to prove. Just take the definition of $B^\perp$:
$$v \in B^\perp \Longleftrightarrow \forall\, b \in B: \langle v,b \rangle = 0.$$
Now ask yourself, if $v,w \in B^\perp$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, do we have $\lambda v + w \in B^\perp$?

Comment: Yes, the criteria of linearity hold, by virtue of the inner product rules, I'm not so sure about the implication of B⊥ containing the zero vector.

How do we guarantee that B⊥ contains the zero-vector, if B does not? (since B it's a subset, and may not contain it?)

Comment: I doesn't matter if $B$ contains it. $\langle v,b \rangle$ is always zero if $v = 0$.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks a lot. I'm a college freshman in CS and have lot to learn.

Comment: @modificaz If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to it. This will remove it from the unanswered queue.